# Prove or disprove the uniform continuity of $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1+|z|}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I tried using the definition of the continuity to try and find a $\delta$ but I got stuck here
$$ |f(w) - f(z)| = |\frac{w^2 \cdot (1+|z|) - z^2 \cdot (1+|w|)}{(1+|w|)\cdot(1+|z|)}|$$
What can I do to find a suitable $\delta$ that would end my proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, $|z| \le |w|$. Then
$$
f(w) - f(z) = \frac{w^2-z^2}{1+|w|} + z^2 \left( \frac{1}{1+|w|} - \frac{1}{1+|z|} \right) \\
= \frac{w+z}{1+|w|} (w-z) + \frac{z^2}{(1+|w|)(1+|z|)} (|z| - |w|) 
$$
and therefore
$$
\begin{align}
|f(w) - f(z)| &\le \frac{|w|+|z|}{1+|w|} |w-z| + \frac{|z|^2}{(1+|w|)(1+|z|)} |w-z| \\
&\le \frac{2|w|}{1+|w|} |w-z|+ \frac{|w||z|}{(1+|w|)(1+|z|)} |w-z| \\
&\le 3 |w-z|
\end{align}
$$
so that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous (and in particular uniformly continuous).

Comment: This is great. Would have never thought of this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this but I have a question for you. How did you the 3 at the end ?

Comment: @Zntzozt: Each factor $\frac{|z|}{1+|z|}$ and $\frac{|w|}{1+|w|}$ is less than one.

Comment: I meant the last step. I got $\frac{3|w||z| + 2|w|}{(1+|w|)(1+|z|)}$

Comment: @Zntzozt: We have $|f(w) - f(z) |\le 2 \frac{|w|}{1+|w|} |w-z| + \frac{|w|}{1+|w|} \frac{|z|}{1+|z|} |w-z| < 2|w-z| + |w-z| = 3|w-z|$

Comment: Got it :3. Thanks again :)